# Не работают генераторы

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Не работают генераторы, выкидывает ошибку

```
 Can't find variable: regeneratorRuntime
```

вот код где возникает ошибка

```
 function* generateSequence() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  return 3;
}

let generator = generateSequence();

let one = generator.next();

console.log(JSON.stringify(one));
```

Вот скомпилированный код webpack.

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "/static/";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";

    var _marked = [generateSequence].map(regeneratorRuntime.mark);

    function generateSequence() {
      return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function generateSequence$(_context) {
        while (1) {
          switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
            case 0:
              _context.next = 2;
              return 1;

            case 2:
              _context.next = 4;
              return 2;

            case 4:
              return _context.abrupt("return", 3);

            case 5:
            case "end":
              return _context.stop();
          }
        }
      }, _marked[0], this);
    }

    var generator = generateSequence();

    var one = generator.next();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(one));

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

Вот часть конфига webpack

```
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']}
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Не надо приводить весь конфиг - оставьте только настройки `babel`. Вместо этого приведите файл, где возникает ошибка, в двух версиях (исходной и скомпилированной). Желательно, возьмите для пробы файл, состоящий из одного пустого генератора.

Comment: Ну вроде щас привел минимальный пример.

Comment: Прочитайте еще раз мой первый комментарий. Я что просил сделать?

Comment: `plugins: [["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }]]`

Comment: Если это добавить к лоадеру, то ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было добавить transform-regenerator в плагины

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'],
      plugins: [
        ["transform-runtime"],
        ["transform-regenerator"]
      ],
   }
}
```